# sftp permisos 775 y 664

Tags: ubuntu, sftp

He configurado con los siguientes comandos un virtual host:

```
sudo chown -R $USER:$USER /var/www/miweb.com
sudo find /var/www/miweb.com -type f -exec chmod 644 {} \;
sudo find /var/www/miweb.com -type d -exec chmod 755 {} \;
```

funcionaba perfecto ya q por sftp siempre subía carpetas con 755 y archivos 644 dentro de miweb.com, pero hace unos días sube carpetas como 775 y archivos como 664.

¿Que puedo hacer para que al subir por sftp vuelva a ser 755 y 644 automáticamente, y no tener que cambiar los permisos cada vez que hago un cambio?

Más información:

- lo hago todo con un usuario NO root llamado losito.
- groups losito -> losito sudo www-data
- me conecto por sftp con el mismo usuario (losito)
- Posteriormente puedo cambiar tanto por sftp como por línea de comandos los permisos.
- ls -l /var/www/miweb.com -> drwxr-xr-x 16 losito losito 4096 Sep 27 04:31 miweb.com
- todos lo archivos contenidos en miweb.com son propiedad de losito.
- todo esto me sucede desde que ejecuté un archivo .sh que contenía esos comandos.

gracias

Comment: no hay nadie que sepa pq pasa esto?

Comment: Puedes poner el contenido del script .sh para ver que pudo cambiar... Puede ser que se haya modificado el **umask** para esa ruta...

Comment: Todo parece indicar que el segundo 7 (permiso del grupo) es aplicado porque "losito" es miembro del grupo con derechos y la estructura los hereda de él. Cuando actuaba como root sólo se aplicaba 7 al propietario.